Dependent prompt in fastapi
Inside update_item function , i am trying to create a parameter item which should take either true or false . If true then it should call class Item and again ask for two more parameter a and b (can be string) and return those a and b (i have marked lines as ---->).
from typing import Annotated, Union
 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Path
from pydantic import BaseModel,Depends
 
app = FastAPI()
 
 
class Item:
    async def __init__(a: Union[str, None] = None, b: Union[str, None] = None): #---------->>>>>>>>>>
        return (a,b)
 
 
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    item_id: Annotated[int, Path(title="The ID of the item to get", ge=0, le=1000)],
    q: Union[str, None] = None,
    item: Item = Depends(),    # ------->>>>>>>> this prompt should be bool
):
    results = {"item_id": item_id}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q})
    if item:
        results.update({"item": item}) #------>>>>>>> if true then call Item class and ask for two more string values and return those values
    return results 


Wouldn't it make more sense to allow item as None / null, and only provide an object if you want it to be used? That way you can actually express "it shouldn't be set or it should be an object like this" in the definition, instead of having to work around having both a boolean parameter, and then having a second parameter which should only be used if the first parameter is set to a specific value.
